# My req.params.id is undefined. How can I fix my route to make it work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, req

I am testing my function `getIndividualTwitt` on Postman and getting undefined when I console.log the req.params.id. This is happening exclusively in this route. I would appreciate any help that you could apare.

**index.js**

```
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/profiles',require('../Server/routes/profile'))
app.use('/users',require('../Server/routes/users'))
app.use('/dashboard',require('../Server/routes/dashboard'))
```

**routes/profiles.js**

```
router.post('/:name',authorization,controller.createProfile)
router.get('/:id',authorization,controller.getProfile)
router.delete('/:id',authorization,controller.deleteProfile)
router.get('/twitt/:id',controller.getIndividualTwitt)
```

**controllers/profiles.js**

```
getIndividualTwitt:async(res,req)=>{
  try {
    console.log('hello')
    console.log(req.params.id) //prints undefined
    //const twitt=await connectTwitt.getTwitt(req.params.id)
       
    //res.send(twitt)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

**Postman request:**

```
GET  http://localhost:3002/profiles/twitt/8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is in the order of your defined endpoints. Express execute code from top to bottom, so when you call `/profiles/twitt/8` endpoint. it will find a match in the following router config:

```js
router.get('/:id',authorization,controller.getProfile)
```

### Solution

Reverse the order of defined endpoints, like this:

```
router.get('/twitt/:id',controller.getIndividualTwitt)
router.get('/:id',authorization,controller.getProfile)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked along with the response below.

Answer (score 2):

replace argument order for request and response, `req` comes first:

```
getIndividualTwitt:async(req,res)=>{
//...
```

Comment: Thank you you are so sharp. It worked alon with the first response. Because I had two mistakes.

Comment: @Elorriaga25 no, it's just arguments, else it wouldn't log undefined..